# Setting button text with myButton.setText prevents animation from happening

Tags: android, animation, settext

I have the weirdest bug in my android code.

Basically, I'm streaming video with the Camera, and I have a button to start and stop the stream, call it `myButton`.

If I click on the button to START the stream, I have code that does `myButton.setText("stop")`, so that the button now says stop if the user wants to stop the stream.

In my `onTouchEvent`, I have code that detects a swipe up or a swipe down, and make a menu disappear/appear accordingly.

The swiping up and down animates my menu to slide out of the screen or slide back into the screen. It works perfectly fine before I try to start streaming, but if I ever click the start streaming button WHILE the menu is off the screen (translated `-menuView.getHeight()` distance away to make it off the screen), then if I try to swipe the menu back down again, it won't appear. However, it definitely receives the `onTouchEvent` because if I click the stop button (`myButton.setText("start")` will execute), then the menu immediately pops into the middle of the screen without any animation (it seems as if the animation must have happened invisibly).

Anyone have any insight into what could be causing this? Have been searching around everywhere and looking it up but haven't had any luck. Thanks

Updated with relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ToggleButton clickedButton;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start_stop_stream:
            if (!recording) {
                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        startRecording();
                    }
                };
                t.start();
                startStopButton.setText("Stop");
                startStopButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            } else {
                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        stopRecording();
                    }
                };
                t.start();
                startStopButton.setText("Start");
                startStopButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downTouch = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(menuView != null){
                releaseTouch = touchevent.getY();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                if (downTouch < releaseTouch && Math.abs(downTouch-releaseTouch) > 100) {

                    menuView.animate().translationY(0);
                    editor.putString("menuDisplayed", "True");
                    editor.apply();
                    return true;
                }
                if (downTouch > releaseTouch  && downTouch-releaseTouch > 100) {
                    menuView.animate().translationY(-menuView.getHeight());

                    rtmpURL = rtmpURLText.getText().toString();
                    editor.putString("rtmpUrl", rtmpURL);
                    editor.putString("menuDisplayed", "False");
                    editor.apply();
                    Log.v("EditText", rtmpURLText.getText().toString());
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: just added it hope it helps

Comment: might not be relevant but are you executing animate() on the UI Thread?

Comment: yes animate is on the UI thread